# How do you access network preferences from the Terminal?

Tags: terminal, network

I can't seem to find how to open the network preferences from the Terminal. What Terminal command will open up the Network preferences window as if having gone by System Preferences > Network ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Typing

```
open /System/Library/PreferencePanes/Network.prefPane/
```

works for me on Lion. You can substitute `Network.prefPane` for any of the preference panes in the `PreferencePanes` folder. This also switches to the correct pane even if System Preferences is already open.