# Using AppleScript to click radio buttons

Tags: macos, applescript, dock

I think this is a bug in Mac OS X: with a dual monitor setup, the Dock switches to the 2nd (not main) monitor from time to time.

To fix this issue, I open the Dock, and click both the "Left" and "Bottom" radio buttons for the "Position on Screen" item.

I need to automate this with AppleScript. I could open the Dock using this script, but I'm not sure how to click the Left and then Bottom radio button in AppleScript.

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    set the current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.dock"
    activate
end tell
```

I tried to add some code in the script, but it does not work.

```
click radiobutton "Left"
```

---

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest you use the Record button in Script Editor to have it generate code for you as you click the button you want. This will do two things: first, it will generate a working script, and second, you can learn from that script.

Comment: @tubedogg, the Record feature in the AppleScript Editor doesn't work at all in most cases and incompletely in other cases. Finder is one of the few apps it works with. Frankly, I've found it to be a useless feature.

Comment: @prosseek, I've updated my answer to work with OS X 10.11.6, as explained in the "Note:" at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click the *radio buttons* in more then one way.

After the `tell application "System Preferences"` *block* use a `tell application "System Events"` *block*, e.g.:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    set the current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.dock"
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
   click radio button 1 of radio group 1 of window 1 of process "System Preferences"
end tell
```

In this first usage, *radio button* 1 is **Left**, *radio button* 2 is **Bottom** and *radio button* 3 is **Right**.

Or:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    set the current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.dock"
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
   click radio button "Left" of radio group 1 of window "Dock" of process "System Preferences"
end tell
```

In this second usage, use **Left**, **Bottom** or **Right** directly and you can also use **Dock** in place of **window 1**. (The latter of which you could do in any of these examples.)

Or:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    set the current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.dock"
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    click (every radio button whose value of attribute "AXTitle" is "Left") of radio group 1 of window 1 of process "System Preferences"
end tell
```

In this third usage, use **Left**, **Bottom** or **Right** for the value of `(every radio button whose value of attribute "AXTitle" is "?")` where the `?` is one of these values.

Note: These examples have been tested under OS X 10.11.6 and work as now edited. I added
 `of radio group 1` between *radio button* and *window*. For use in OS X 10.8.5 remove `of radio group 1` from the *code*.

Comment: None of the three code works for me (Mac OS X 10.11.6). The first example: Invalid index." number -1719 from radio button 1 of window 1 of process "System Preferences". The second example: Can’t get radio button \"Left\" of window \"Dock\" of process \"System Preferences\"." number -1728 from radio button "Left" of window "Dock" of process "System Preferences". The last example: missing value.

Comment: @prosseek, These all work for me in OS X 10.8.5, which it want I'm using at the moment. I'll spin up an OS X 10.11.6 after lunch and see what's changed.

Comment: I just tested these under macOS sierra 10.12 and they work as written.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than clicking buttons, something that is slower and more error-prone, it's better to change the settings directly using AppleScript.

To change set screen edge setting, run

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell dock preferences
        set properties to {screen edge:bottom}
    end tell
end tell
```

if you want it to go on the left, just exchange 'bottom' for 'left' above.

To get all possible settings, 'get properties' instead of set.